# python file decompile encrypted file

Tags: python, encryption

I try to decode pyc python file using python-decompile3.

The file is encrypted by python libs cryptography and bcrypt

This is my command

```
decompyle3 names.pyc
```

but i have this error, how to fix it

```
C:\Users\virtualWin\Desktop\>decompyle3 names.pyc
    # decompyle3 version 3.7.6
    # Python bytecode 3.9 (3425)
    # Decompiled from: Python 3.7.6 (tags/v3.7.6:43364a7ae0, Dec 19 2019, 00:42:30) [MSC v.1916 64 bit (AMD64)]
    # Embedded file name: dist\obf\names.py
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "C:\Users\virtualWin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\Scripts\decompyle3-script.py", line 11, in <module>
        load_entry_point('decompyle3', 'console_scripts', 'decompyle3')()
      File "c:\users\virtualwin\desktop\python-decompile3-master (2)\python-decompile3-master\decompyle3\bin\decompile.py", line 190, in main_bin
        src_base, out_base, pyc_paths, source_paths, outfile, **options
      File "c:\users\virtualwin\desktop\python-decompile3-master (2)\python-decompile3-master\decompyle3\main.py", line 304, in main
        do_fragments,
      File "c:\users\virtualwin\desktop\python-decompile3-master (2)\python-decompile3-master\decompyle3\main.py", line 222, in decompile_file
        compile_mode="exec",
      File "c:\users\virtualwin\desktop\python-decompile3-master (2)\python-decompile3-master\decompyle3\main.py", line 140, in decompile
        compile_mode=compile_mode,
      File "c:\users\virtualwin\desktop\python-decompile3-master (2)\python-decompile3-master\decompyle3\semantics\pysource.py", line 2172, in code_deparse
        scanner = get_scanner(version, is_pypy=is_pypy)
      File "c:\users\virtualwin\desktop\python-decompile3-master (2)\python-decompile3-master\decompyle3\scanner.py", line 535, in get_scanner
        "scan.Scanner%s(show_asm=show_asm)" % v_str, locals(), globals()
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "c:\users\virtualwin\desktop\python-decompile3-master (2)\python-decompile3-master\decompyle3\scanners\scanner39.py", line 36, in __init__
        Scanner37Base.__init__(self, 3.9, show_asm)
      File "c:\users\virtualwin\desktop\python-decompile3-master (2)\python-decompile3-master\decompyle3\scanners\scanner37base.py", line 101, in __init__
        self.opc.END_FINALLY,
    AttributeError: module 'xdis.opcodes.opcode_39' has no attribute 'END_FINALLY'
```

Answer (score -1):

decompyle3 is not support Python 3.9 now.

Please see https://github.com/rocky/python-decompile3/issues/45 and https://github.com/rocky/python-uncompyle6/issues/353